# Cannot change launcher icon android

Tags: android, android-launcher

I am trying to change launcher icon for the application I am developing but the icon remains same (Android Studio 3.0). I have tried changing it from *manifest.xml* and *minimap*. It appears to be picking up icon from two XML files named as ic_launcher_background.xml and ic_launcher_forground.xml. I have tried deleting these files but safe delete is not allowing me to. I am attaching screenshot of my project.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7czJ.png)

Comment: Try with rebuild once and after that install your application. Because sometimes andtoid studio not update this type of changes it will take from caches. So try with rebuild and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

Copy & paste launcher icon .png file to mipmap folder. Better if you add icon to all screen types hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi & etc. Then change android manifest code like this.

```
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
```

Comment: I have tried that already. Not working as i have mentioned in my question, it
 is picking up icon from 2 xml files.

Comment: why you pick them from xml. Add them in mipmap or drawable folder. Those folders use for icons, pictures & other image resources. You can't pick them from xmls. Because android don't use xml for launcher icons.

Comment: I said "android studio is automatically picking up from xml files". That is exactly why i asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

try to move your your ic_launcher_torch icon into mipmap directory

Comment: I have tried that already. Replaced all the images in mipmap directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the *ic_launcher_torch.png* file from *drawables* folder.
2. Right click on res folder> New Image Asset > Icon type > Action Bar and Tab Icons > Asset type - image > Choose your logo in path > finish.
3. Add `android:icon="@mipmap/yourLogoName"`

The  image will be saved in */res/drawable* folder. Learn more: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html

Comment: I have done exactly what you told me to, it still isn't changing launcher icon

Comment: Don't use XML file for launcher icons. You may need to refresh/rebuild/clean your project if you're facing issues. If nothing happens, uninstall and reinstall the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

make changes in manifest file at both location
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"

First uninstall the app from the phone(dont reinstall when you already have it installed)
After the app is uninstalled ,try installing it once again .
I had the same issue ,wasted around 2 hrs and this worked for me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, add some more description and code if it's required to understand the answer because it will resolve someone else problem ASAP