# Change the android launch icon from default (other methods suggested haven't worked)

Tags: android, android-studio

I am building a simple app using Android Studio.
I have inserted a 512x512 png image called 'testicon' as my launch icon using the recommended method in Android Studio (Creating a new image asset and following the instuctions) which has put all the right sized images in the res folders. I have changed the names in my manifest file:

```
    android:icon="@mipmap/testicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/testicon_round"
```

I have tried all the suggestions on
[Cannot change launcher icon android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47165425/cannot-change-launcher-icon-android)

I have deleted any old files in the res folder. 
Have tried clean project.
It runs fine with my icon on the emulator, but I always get the default green droid icon on my phone, whatever I change. I uninstall and reinstall the app each time.
My phone is Honor 10 lite running Android Pie.

Any other suggestions as to what the problem is would be welcome!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems to have been a problem with my phone. Once it updated to Android 10 it sorted itself out. Seems like there are lots of different answers to this question.

Comment: Try this solution(the answer I gave) its work for me and if its work for you also please vote up..

Comment: Thanks. I think the problem was with my phone as now it has done an update, the icon can easily be changed.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to remove below line and then uninstall app and reinstall and then you have your icon but first check image is it ok ?**

```
    // remove below line in your manifest

    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/testicon_round"
```